# What's stopping the Tonnerre family from taking over the Suoh company?

Tags: plot-explanation, ouran-high-school

In the anime series "Ouran High School Host Club" Kyoya Ootori stops the Tonnerre family's hostile take over of Ootori Medical, but nothing is said about the Suoh family's company.

Couldn't Eclair's family, out of spite for Tamaki ending the engagement, try the very same thing with the Suoh company?

It was a concern for Tamaki's father and grandmother. I believe it was the whole reason the grandmother set up the meeting between Eclair and Tamaki. So that they'd get engaged and the Suoh family would still have a hand in their business.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclair family could take over the Suoh company out of spite for Tamaki ending the engagement. I believe that the scene where Tamaki leaves Ms.Eclair is very impactful on her and thus stops this action. Tamaki is literally about to see his mother for the first time in years, swore to never speak to anyone but his soon to be wife. Ms.Eclair knows Tamaki is not happy and so when his friends reinstate his sense of belonging, of course he would leave. Ms.Eclair knew that the ties Tamaki had to his friends were strong enough to break their arrangement. With the alliance of the Ootori and Suoh families, it would probably look very bad on the Eclairs to take over the Suoh company with the information they all know of. Plus, there would be nothing to truly gain from it as they did not mention an eligible male aire to either company.